# Change in getSupportFragment().getFragments() in Android version 22 to 23

Tags: android, android-fragments

Are there major changes in this method or anything related to Fragments?

I'm experiencing this problem wherein, I'm getting the list of fragments in the activity using:

`getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()`

I have a list of fragment from my adapter as follows

- `Fragment A`
- `Fragment B`

Now using the list I got from the `getFragments()` method, I can fetch each of these fragments using their index, 0 for Fragment A, then 1 for Fragment B.

The code works fine for version 22. However, when I updated to version 23, the order suddenly reverses.

Using index 0, I am getting Fragment B and using index 1, I'm getting Fragment A instead. And it's messing up my code.

Any one have an idea why this is happening?

Do note that I'm not sure if it's really the version update that's causing this. I'm just assuming because this only happens when I'm in my version 23 code.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation does not mention any change as such. The following is what the documentation says

> Get a list of all fragments that have been added to the fragment manager.

That is all. It does not talk about the order in which the `Fragment`s are returned. There must be something else affecting the order, though. I'm afraid you will have to look into the source for that.

Because the documentation does not talk about the order at all, I don't think you can help it even if there is a change.

Comment: no it's ok. I just want to understand why it happened. I can make a patch to reverse the order of the fragment list when I'm fetching the fragment, but I'm not even sure if it really reverses the list or some other pattern. thanks for the tip though, I guess I'll just look into the source code itself.

Comment: @kishidp I really don't recommend reversing the list and retrieving by index. You should be able to Identify your fragments in a robust manner or you'll end up with `NullPointerException`s.